# Need help getting DPM to work

Tags: authorize.net

First off, I am using DPM because my understanding is that Accept.js does not support e-check and the whole reason that I am involved in making this update is to add e-check support.

I am trying to rewrite a classic ASP page for DPM in VB.Net using razor syntax. I have repeatedly received the error response:

The following errors have occurred.
(13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.

I know the default response. I am using the wrong login in or posting to the wrong URL. I am posting using the same URL that my current ASP page is posting to and I am using the same x_login value.

Also, if I go to this URL:

https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll?x_version=3.1&x_type=AUTH_ONLY&x_amount=1.99&x_car... it returns that the credit card has expired. If I enter an invalid x_login on that url it returns "The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive." If I enter my valid x_login and an invalid x_tran_key I receive "This transaction cannot be accepted."

So, I know that my x_login is correct and that I am posting to the correct URL.

In order to eliminate any coding issues, I put together a simple form just to post static information to the URL:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll"> 

<input type=hidden id="x_login" name="x_login" value='MY_LOGIN'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_cust_id" name="x_cust_id" value='106400289'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_card_num" name="x_card_num" value='5424000000000015'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_exp_date" name="x_exp_date" value='12-17'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_card_code" name="x_card_code" value='123'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_fp_hash" name="x_fp_hash" value='84EFB49E5F4A8F7CB3EEB3C6A1B2B305'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_amount" name="x_amount" value='123.60'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_fp_timestamp" name="x_fp_timestamp" value='1493038728'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_fp_sequence" name="x_fp_sequence" value='531'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_relay_url" name="x_relay_url" value='https://www.my.com/CCPayment2.vbhtml'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_relay_response" name="x_relay_response" value='Y'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_type" name="x_type" value='AUTH_CAPTURE'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_currency_code" name="x_currency_code" value='USD'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_version" name="x_version" value='3.1'/>
<input type=hidden id="x_invoice_num" name="x_invoice_num" value='2'/>

<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I verified that my hash value was correct using the link at:
http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCode99.html

This returns the error message:
(13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.

In researching I did find where one developer received that message because he used the same test card and amount and evidently that message is returned as the result of a duplicate. So I changed the amount, the card, the time stapm, and the hash and tried again with the same result. I also used both the "name" and "id" within the hidden fields since I have seen references to both of those.

I would appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: Are you testing in production? Or in the sandbox?

Comment: FYI, it's not a good idea to ask a question and then walk away. Then you cannot respond to comments and the window for getting help gets smaller jeopardizing your chance to get assistance. Always hang around and be ready to answer any questions users may have so they can try to help you.

Comment: This test is in production since I know that I have operational account there.

Comment: FYI, [DPM is going away](https://developer.authorize.net/api/upgrade_guide/). You'll need to re-implement this in the near future and may want to consider using an alternative implementation method.

Comment: Are you sure you're using your API login and not the control panel login?

Comment: I would like to use the Accept.js method, but as far as I can tell it doesn't support e-check and e-check is the reason I am having to do this. I have a functional asp classic version working that supports credit card only.

Comment: Yes, definitely using the API login. Using the same login and transaction key for hashing as being used in the functional credit card version.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for an answer to this in the future, the message:

(13) The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.

evidently appears for more reasons than supplying the wrong login id or connecting to the wrong url at least as far as DPM is concerned.

In my instance, the refresh on my link "https://www.my.com/CCPayment2.vbhtml" contained an invalid URL. Once I discovered and fixed this, everything worked fine.